# Problem with an integral equality in the generalized equipartition theorem

Tags: statistical-mechanics

To prove it, as Huang does with the microcanonical ensemble, the following equality must be valid. In all sincerity, I can not understand why it must be true. I would appreciate enormously some help with it or some good reference where it explicitly elaborates on the argument.[image]

Comment: Please write your equations using MathJax as the question is not searchable as written.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less the fundamental theorem of calculus; it's not really statmech trickery.
$$
h \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_0^a f(x) dx = h f(a) \approx \int_a^{a+h} f(x) dx,
$$
where everything is only keeping terms of order $O(h)$.